# How do I add a scrollbar to my Java GUI window?

Tags: java

I've gone through a lot of the questions asked about this topic but they all seem to focus on textboxes instead. I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong because no errors show up on Eclipse, yet when I run the program, it doesn't work.

Basically, I have created a small quiz by using WindowBuilder. I can see the JScrollPane and I have added it. I want it to work so that in case the user resizes the window to a way smaller size, a scroll bar appear so they can scroll through the rest of the questions.

From what I understand, I have to use my JPanel and add it into my JScrollPane... But that doesn't seem to work. For such a small thing, I've been stuck on this for an hour.

Here is the code I have so far (EDITED):

```
setTitle("Quiz");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 460, 794);
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(component);` `contentPane.add(scrollPane)`

Comment: [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: @CardinalSystem what do you do with (component)?

Comment: @JayE Component is whatever you are scrolling over.

Comment: @CardinalSystem so I edited it by trying to create a new JPanel that stores all the questions and answers instead of using the JFrame. I have edited the code to look similar to your's but it's giving me an error and won't run. What do I do?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/ecicifasef.scala